# Take a screenshot of a hidden control

Tags: vb.net, bitmap, webbrowser-control, screenshot, minimize

All I want to do is to be able to take a screenshot of a control (in this instance a `webbrowser`) while the form is hidden-minimized or the webbrowser is on the background.

I want to take it as a bitmap using a timer, every time timer ticks I want to take an image-bitmap of that control. I'm abled to do it when the control is on the top.

```
Private Function Screenshot(x1 as integer,x2 as integer,y1 as integer,y2 as integer) As Bitmap
    Dim bounds As Rectangle
    Dim screenshot As System.Drawing.Bitmap
    Dim graph As Graphics
    bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds
    screenshot = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(x1 - x2, y1- y2, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    graph = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot)
    graph.CopyFromScreen(x1, y1, 0, 0, bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)
    Return screenshot
End Function
```

Comment: Show the code you are using to get this screenshot when on top

Comment: Bear in mind browsers often don't bother rendering content at all when they're in the background, so trying to capture that content might be a wasted effort anyway.

Comment: there is a `Control.DrawToBitmap` method but Windows doesnt update anything the user can't see (as when behind something or minimized).

Comment: I apparently can't put my webbrowser on top, it needs to be on the back.

Comment: DrawToBitmap should work, even when the window is at the back of the Z order.

Comment: thanks for idea but I can't get control.drawtobitmap working even if the control is on top, it gives a blank bitmap, any idea why(I'll try but it seems that it doesn't work)?

Comment: DrawToBitmap() does not work for a few controls in the toolbox, the kind that have non-standard rendering behavior.  WebBrowser is one of them.  IHTMLElementRender::DrawToDC() doesn't work anymore either, put to pasture by GPU acceleration and competition with Chrome.  You can only have a shot at it with the code you posted, having the browser window in the foreground is a rock-hard requirement.

Comment: What about WM_PRINT? I couldn't find any examples anyway.